# Does bounty history get migrated along with a question?

Tags: discussion, bounties, migration, vote-to-close

I somehow think this is a dupe, so sorry if it is.  My search-fu is turning up empty...

Do migrated questions retain bounty history?  For example, say a question has a bounty set on one site before enough people vote it closed and migrate it.  The bounty expires on the one site, then it gets enough close votes to migrate.  Is it no longer possible to accept that answer on the target site since the bounty on the first site expired?

I know this probably doesn't happen that often on SO, but I've seen it a few times on SF.  Mainly when the OP doesn't want the question migrated....

Answer (score 4):

No form of bounties are carried over to another site upon migration.

The user who was awarded the bounty loses the full amount immediately upon migration, and the user who offered it will regain that amount once the migration stub gets deleted. The bounty is not recreated on the destination site in any form and will not appear in the revision history.

Comment: I guess asking duplicate questions is an effective way to get quick answers, Lol. Thanks for the answer